# Passing Params to Symfony Routes

Tags: php, symfony1

I have a defined route that displays a dynamic page:

```
page_show:
  url:     /:domain_slug/:slug
  class:   sfPropelRoute
  options:
    model: Page
    type:  object
method: doSelectByDomain
  param:   { module: page, action: show }
  requirements:
    sf_method: [get]
```

This works great, but now I want my homepage URI to route to a specific page. To do that, I assume that I have to pass the `:domain_slug` and `:slug` values of the page I want to display as the homepage. That's fine, but I can't seem to track down any documentation or example that shows me how to go about doing that.

Is it possible to specify specific variable values in a route? In this case, I want to pass `:domain_slug => portal, :slug => dashboard` (that syntax doesn't work, btw). Essentially, I want to create a homepage route that looks something like this:

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  class: sfPropelRoute
  param: { module: page, action: show, array( :domain_slug => portal, :slug => dashboard ) }
  options:
    model: Page
    type: object
    method: doSelectByDomain
```

But different enough that it, you know, works. :-) I suppose I could create a simple route to a different method, modify the request parameters manually and forward to the `executeShow()` method, but that's a hack I'd rather avoid if a more elegant solution is available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a way to do this that worked (or maybe I just couldn't manage to do it correctly). My solution was to create the route and pass it through a custom method that does the work to specify the appropriate page details:

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  class: sfPropelRoute
  options:
    model: Page
    type: object
    method: doSelectHomepage
  param: { module: page, action: show ) }
  requirements:
    sf_method: [get]
```

The `doSelectHomepage()` method does all of the work I was hoping I'd be able to do by hardcoding values in the route itself.

Comment: that's horrible. is this really the solution? symfony is such a stupid framework...i'm in the same boat and really don't want to do that... you're supposed to just be able to pass in param: { misc_arg: value } according to everything i'm reading, but it doesn't work. argh

Answer (score 3):

You can define values in the `param` key of the route... for example:

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  class: sfPropelRoute
  param: { module: page, action: show, domain_slug: portal, slug: dashboard}
  options:
    model: Page
    type: object
    method: doSelectByDomain
```

At least thats how it works with a non propel/doctrine route. I assume it should be the same with any type of route in the framework.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too. When the workflow reaches my custom handler method (`doSelectByDomain`), no parameters are there. The array is completely empty.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it did work, it was just the order in which the routes were defined. The first answer is correct. It may have worked for you if you added "homepage" rule BEFORE the "page_show" rule. So maybe Symfony isn't as stupid as I thought...No, no, it is. It's just not that bad.